# How to get the rendered html by AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

how to get the html rendered inside a div, after it is rendered and put it inside the scope of controller ?

I am new to angular and though i know the basics of directives i cant seem to get the rendered html after it is rendered any link that would guide to a solution will also be appreciated.

Comment: That seems like something you really should not do. controllers shouldn't mess with HTML. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: working on a prototype i want to render it inside of a div or a [Glass Layer Popup](http://glasslayerpopup.oft.pl).the div part is easy how do i render the same html inside the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var html = angular.element(':visible').html()
```